# Automatically Delete Row With Specific Character in Googlescript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have here a googlescript that submits a form into the spreadsheet. My problem is in the last part of my script,   the delete function doesnt work. I dont know where did I go wrong, i have tried running the delete function on a single gs file and it worked well.

```
var sheetName = 'Get Passenger'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup2() {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost2(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
        'result': 'success',
        'row': nextRow
      }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  } catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
        'result': 'error',
        'error': e
      }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  } finally {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Get Passenger');
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();

    var rowsDeleted = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
      var row = values[i];
      if (row[19] == 'delete') {
        // This searches all cells in columns A 
        // (change to row[1] for columns B and so on) 
        // and deletes row if cell is empty or has value 'delete'.
        deleteriderlessthan3mins()
      }
    }
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `the delete function doesnt work` mean? It doesn't get called? What makes you think that's the case? Please consider providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the code related to this `delete function` which doesn't work.

Comment: Please try `openById`

Comment: I don't know, just a guess: perhaps one of the `return` statements fires before the `finally` section comes into play?

Comment: i have tried putting my delete function before the first return but it doesnt work.

Comment: Consider providing the code related to this function that "doesn't work".

Comment: @ErwinManalang Your shared script has only 2 functions, none of which is named "delete"... Please consider reading [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make the question better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Get Passenger');
const rg = sh.getDataRange();
const vs = rg.getValues();
let d = 0;
vs.forEach((r, i) => {
  if (r[19] == 'delete') {
    sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++)
  }
});
}
```

Comment: i've tried also but that doesnt delete's the row with 'delete' character. I dont know where can i add that function